# How can I plot conditional expressions?

Tags: plotting

I want plot an expression that includes some integrals.

The values of these integrals are conditional expressions, and this is making plotting difficult.

My code:

```
A = 14*(1 + I)
As = 14*(1 - I)
Ω = 2*Pi*0.01*10^6
X = 10^7
k = 2*Pi*0.1*10^6
n = -1.425
s = Integrate[((2*k)*(4*X*X*A*A*As*As)*E^(I*ω*t))/
    ((2*I*X*As*As*2*I*X*A*A + (-4*I*X*A*As - k - I*ω + 2*I*X*n)*
       (4*I*X*As*A - k - I*ω - 2*I*X*n))*(2*I*X*As*As*2*I*X*A*A + 
      (4*I*X*As*A - k + I*ω - 2*I*X*n)*(-4*I*X*A*As - k + I*ω + 
        2*I*X*n))), {ω, -Infinity, Plus[Infinity]}]
H = Integrate[((2*k)*(-2*I*X*As*As)*(-4*I*X*As*A - k + I*ω + 2*I*X*n))/
     E^(I*ω*t)/((2*I*X*As*As*2*I*X*A*A + 
      (4*I*X*As*A - k - I*ω - 2*I*X*n)*(-4*I*X*As*A - k - I*ω + 
        2*I*X*n))*(2*I*X*As*As*2*I*X*A*A + 
      (-4*I*X*As*As - k + I*ω + 2*I*X*n)*(4*I*X*As*A - k + I*ω - 
        2*X*n))), {ω, -Infinity, Plus[Infinity]}]
Q = Integrate[((2*k)*(2*I*X*A*A)*(4*I*X*A*As - k + I*ω - 2*I*X*n)*
     E^(I*ω*t))/((2*I*X*As*As*2*I*X*A*A + 
      (4*I*X*As*A - k + I*ω - 2*I*X*n)*(-4*I*X*As*A - k + I*ω + 
        2*I*X*n))*(2*I*X*As*As*2*I*X*A*A + 
      (-4*I*X*As*A - I*ω - k + 2*I*X*n)*(4*I*X*A*As - k - I*ω - 
        2*I*X*n))), {ω, -Infinity, Plus[Infinity]}]
G = Integrate[((2*I*X*A*A)*(-2*I*X*As*As))/E^(I*ω*t)/
    ((2*I*X*As*As)*(2*I*X*A*A) + (4*I*X*A*As - k + I*ω - 2*I*X*n)*
       (-4*I*X*A*As - k + I*ω + 2*I*X*n))^2, 
   {ω, -Infinity, Plus[Infinity]}]
g = 1 + ((As*As + H)*(A*A + Q) + (As*A + G)*(As*A + s))/(As*As*A*A)

Plot[g, {t, 0,0.00001}, PlotStyle->{Red, Thickness[0.0001]}]
```

How can I plot g?

Comment: Please give us properly formatted Mathematica code so that we can evaluate it. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't use `Assumptions-> Element[t, Reals]` in the integration

Comment: The condition of s and G is that ( t be Real), but the condition of H and Q is (t==0),while H and Q have answer if t is not zero.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem with conditionals can be fixed by evaluating your terms under the assumption that `t ∈ Reals`. For example,

```
A = 14*(1 + I);
As = 14*(1 - I);
Ω = 2*Pi*0.01*10^6;
X = 10^7;
k = 2*Pi*0.1*10^6;
n = -1.425;

s[t_] = 
  Assuming[t ∈ Reals, 
    Integrate[((2*k)*(4*X*X*A*A*As*As)*E^(I*ω*t))/
      ((2*I*X*As*As*2*I*X*A*A + (-4*I*X*A*As - k - I*ω + 2*I*X*n)*
          (4*I*X*As*A - k - I*ω - 2*I*X*n))*
        (2*I*X*As*As*2*I*X*A*A + (4*I*X*As*A - k + I*ω - 2*I*X*n)*(
           -4*I*X*A*As - k + I*ω + 2*I*X*n))), {ω, -∞, ∞}]]
```

Similar definitions should be made for `Q` and `G`, but `H` can be dropped because it evaluates identically to 0.

Now `g` can be defined as

```
g[t_] := 1 + ((As*As)*(A*A + Q[t]) + (As*A + G[t])*(As*A + s[t]))/(As*As*A*A)
```

but your plot still won't work because `g` is a complex-valued function of `t`. Further values of `g` move far from origin very quickly.

```
Table[g[t], {t, Subdivide[1.*^-6, 1.*^-5, 3]}]
```

> `{2.99867 + 0.000346311 I, 3.00161 - 0.0138032 I, 3.04019 + 0.0629924 I, 
>   1.453510426828833*10^118187 - .75989090582087*10^118186 I}`

I suggest you rethink your problem's formulation.